# Enable numbered links on graphic links2

Tags: linux, browser

According to the man page for links2 the number link mode is available only for the text-only version, not the graphic. Is there any way I can enable this mode on the graphic mode, short of editing the source?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to edit the source, I believe; there's actually a section starting on [`html_gr.c` line 870](https://code.google.com/p/pblinks/source/browse/src/html_gr.c?spec=svn9cc4233f0a63dab58b559dd4d074da202961b451&r=9cc4233f0a63dab58b559dd4d074da202961b451#870), where some code has been commented out that would have introduced numbered links in  graphical mode:

```
if (d_opt->num_links) {
  unsigned char s[64];
  unsigned char *fl = format.link, *ft = format.target, *fi = format.image;
  struct form_control *ff = format.form;
  struct js_event_spec *js = format.js_event;
  format.link = format.target = format.image = NULL;
  format.form = NULL;
  format.js_event = NULL;
  s[0] = '[';
  snzprint(s + 1, 62, p->link_num);
  strcat(cast_char s, "]");
  g_put_chars(p, s, strlen(cast_const_char s));
  if (ff && ff->type == FC_TEXTAREA) g_line_break(p);
  if (p->cx < par_format.leftmargin * G_HTML_MARGIN) p->cx = par_format.leftmargin * G_HTML_MARGIN;
  format.link = fl, format.target = ft, format.image = fi;  
  format.form = ff;
  format.js_event = js;
}
```

Merely uncommenting the code didn't work for me; and I didn't find any obvious solutions after playing around for a while.

Someone's going to have to get their hands dirty.